# Is Java caching entire objects or only parts of objects? (Visibility Issues)

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, concurrency, thread-safety

I was trying to intentionally create visibility issues with threads and I got unexpected results:

```
public class DownloadStatus {
    private int totalBytes;
    private boolean isDone;

    public void increment() {
        totalBytes++;
    }

    public int getTotalBytes() {
        return totalBytes;
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
        return isDone;
    }

    public void done() {
        isDone = true;
    }
}
```

```
public class DownloadFileTask implements Runnable {
    DownloadStatus status;

    public DownloadFileTask(DownloadStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("start download");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10_000; i++) { //"download" a 10,000 bytes file each time you run
            status.increment(); //each byte downloaded - update the status
        }
        System.out.println("download ended with: " + status.getTotalBytes()); //**NOTE THIS LINE**
        status.done();
    }
}
```

```
//creating threads, one to download, another to wait for the download to be done.
public static void main(String[] args) {
        DownloadStatus status = new DownloadStatus();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new DownloadFileTask(status));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            while (!status.isDone()) {}
            System.out.println("DONE!!");
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
}
```

So, running this would create a visibility problem - the second thread wouldn't see the updated value since it had cached it before it got written back by the first thread - this causes an endless (while) loop, the second thread is constantly checking the cached isDone(). (at least that's how I think it works).

The thing I don't get is why this visibility problem stops happening when I comment out the line from the second code block that calls `status.getTotalBytes()`.
From my understanding both threads start by caching the status object as-is, so the second thread should constantly check his cached value (and essentially not see the new value updated by the first thread).

Why is this line calling a method in the status object causing this visibility issue? (and more interestingly - why not calling it fixes it?)

Comment: Re, "...both threads start by caching the status object..." Java doesn't cache anything. If there's any cacheing going on (and there will be, in any device that's bigger than a credit card and, in some devices that are smaller) then it's the _hardware_ that's doing it, and the hardware doesn't have any idea where one "object" ends in memory and the next one begins.

Comment: P.S., Testing to find memory visibility issues, race conditons, etc. is problematic. If you obey all of the rules, then your program should behave properly. But if you _break_ the rules there is no guarantee that your program will misbehave. Worst case is when you build a system, test the **** out of it, ship it to customers, and then six months later, everybody gets an OS upgrade or something, and the "memory visibility" issue that was latent in your product all through the testing, suddenly becomes a big deal. (Don't ask me how I know!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call a "visibility problem" is actually a data race.

A single thread sees the effects of its operations in the order they are written. That is if you update a variable and then read it, you'll always see the updated value within that thread.

The effects of a thread's execution may be different when viewed from another thread. This is mainly related to the language and the underlying hardware architecture. The compiler may reorder instructions, delay memory writes while keeping values in registers, or the values may be kept in a cache before written to the main memory. Without an explicit memory barrier, the value in the main memory would not be updated. That's what you call the "visibility problem".

It is likely that there is a memory barrier in `System.println`. So when you execute that line, all updates up to that point will be committed to the main memory, and the other threads can see it. Note that without explicit synchronization, there is still no guarantee that the other threads will see it, because those threads may re-use the value they got for that variable before. There is nothing in the program that tells the compiler/runtime that the values may be changed by other threads.

Comment: Indeed, `System.out.println()` is the "leading cause of confusion" in these things, as `PrintStream.println()` has `synchronized(this)` inside.

Answer (score 0):

This is the race condition between two threads. There is nothing to do with `status.getTotalBytes()` statement in your code. It is the scheduler that decides which thread will run. It is by chance that you are not getting stuck in the infinit loop after commenting the println statement. The main problem in your code that increment and set status should be atomic operation and replace the definition of run method as below. Secondly increment is also not a atomic operation. You can unpredictable results if there is no proper synchronization.

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("start download");
        incrementAndSetStatus();
    }

    public synchronized  void  incrementAndSetStatus(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) { //"download" a 10,000 bytes file each time you run

            status.increment(); //each byte downloaded - update the status
        }
        System.out.println("download ended with: " + status.getTotalBytes()); //**NOTE THIS LINE**
        status.done();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! what made you choose to add `synchronized` over setting the isDone field `volatile`?

Comment: Increment operation is not a atomic operation. Along with done, increment could be race condition.